# Passing string from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I'm trying to pass string from c++ to c#.

```
C++:
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetSurfaceName(wchar_t* o_name);

void GetSurfaceName(wchar_t* o_name)
{
  swprintf(o_name, 20, L"Surface name");
}

C#:
[DllImport("SurfaceReader.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void GetSurfaceName(StringBuilder o_name);

StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder(20);
GetSurfaceName(name);
```

But only first symbol is passed: name[0] == 'S'. Other symbols are nulls. Could you tell me what is  wrong here?

Thanks,
Zhenya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to tell the pinvoke marshaller that the function is using a Unicode string.  The default is CharSet.Ansi, you'll need to use CharSet.Unicode explicitly.  Fix:

```
[DllImport("SurfaceReader.dll", 
           CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, 
           CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void GetSurfaceName(StringBuilder o_name);
```

You'll get a single "S" now because the utf-16 encoded value for "S" looks like a C string with one character.

Do in general avoid magic numbers like "20".  Just add an argument that say how long the string buffer is.  That way you'll *never* corrupt the GC heap by accident.  Pass the StringBuilder.Capacity.  And give the function a return value that can indicate success so you also won't ignore a buffer that's too small.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but instead of using StringBuilder, I would pass from C# char (wchar) array to C++, fill it and then operate with this array in C#.